# BinNavi Debugging Executable with Arguments

Tags: debugging, debuggers

It is about debugging some executable by using Zynamics BinNavi 5.0. And there's no problem if I want to start debugging without any command line parameters (i.e. "my.exe"), but I cannot find a way to start debugging with command line parameters/switches (i.e. "my.exe --do").

I would appreciate any help...

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should run debugger like that (example for linux):
./debugclient a.out 1
and then attach to debugger from binnavi.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question about using BinNavi while debugging.